# OpenStage Phone address book

Tags: provisioning, addressbook, siemens, unify

How can I implement an address book for OpenStage series phones?

I did not find examples with a ready-made address book.
Usually in the book there is a list of members, transitions between pages.

Some examples I found on https://wiki.unify.com/wiki/OpenStage.
But it was not possible to collect an address book from them.

Comment: are you looking for official resources? (resources provided by the maintainer of whatever technology you are using) that's allowed here, but asking for links to resources that are not official is not allowed here (see [/help/dont-ask](/help/dont-ask) #3)

Comment: The official documentation is open for access and it describes examples of XML applications. Among them there is no address book. I'm looking for an example with an address book implemented as an xml application(some XML examle).